# Creating C# Authentication using Forum DB at remote website?

Tags: c#, authentication

I cant seem to find the relevant resource for learning this. I am trying to achieve a simple login for my C# application where users will be required to authenticate to use the application, and such the users account level would determine what can be accessed inside the app.

Lets say i have a forum and i want my users to authenticate via the application using the forum credentials, is this possible? what should i know about Security and how is this accomplished?

My thoughts would be i should be able to authenticate using some kind of SQL library? though i am new to C# so i might not be on the right track here.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

To authenticate with a web site (forum) you need something like OAuth, see this [guide](http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/a-simple-guide-to-using-oauth-with-c-/49) for example. The website needs to provide OAuth.

Authenticating with a web site that was not explicitly designed to support an app client is not really possible, at least not correctly.